# Eviciting occupant of a house who has some equity in it in the US

Tags: real-estate

I bought a house with an ex-colleague and I put up 85% of money and my colleague put up 15%. With an agreement that he would pay rent for the 85%.

Now he has stopped paying rent. What are my options? Can I get him evicted? If yes, what happen to his stakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Owners can't be evicted from their own property. That's one of the fundamental rights of real estate ownership.

You may have a contractual basis for a lawsuit that either leads to payment or provides for forfeiture of their share, but that relies on the details of your specific case and will require specific legal advice from your own lawyer.

Comment: But banks evict people from their homes all the time, how does that work?

Comment: Banks foreclose the loan, taking possession of the property, and evict *former* owners from property that *the bank* owns.

Comment: How should have I gone about it? I am about to go in a similar contract again. What can i do better to protect myself from non-payment of rent? Can have a specific clause added to the contract?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer for specific legal advice.

Comment: @Marci-man yep, get a lawyer. I think in the end you'll have to go the bank route: make it so that he is NOT the owner anymore to evict him.